# django redis with django showing ulimit error

Tags: python, django, redis

Im trying to use redis on my django project and when i try to run thr server using 'redis-server' on the terminal i get the following errors

```
2280:C 23 Nov 15:19:57.938 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting 
oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
2280:C 23 Nov 15:19:57.938 # Redis version=4.0.9, bits=64, 
commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=2280, just started
2280:C 23 Nov 15:19:57.938 # Warning: no config file specified, using 
the default config. In order to specify a config file use redis-server 
/path/to/redis.conf
2280:M 23 Nov 15:19:57.939 # You requested maxclients of 10000 
requiring at least 10032 max file descriptors.
2280:M 23 Nov 15:19:57.939 # Server can't set maximum open files to  
10032 because of OS error: Operation not permitted.
2280:M 23 Nov 15:19:57.939 # Current maximum open files is 4096. 
maxclients has been reduced to 4064 to compensate for low ulimit. If 
you need higher maxclients increase 'ulimit -n'.
2280:M 23 Nov 15:19:57.939 # Creating Server TCP listening socket 
*:6379: bind: Address already in use
```

I have tried all solutions including setting the file max size etc ,still error persists.Im using ubuntu 18.04 .Any other solutions?

Comment: Not a programming problem. Most likely just an other process listening on port 6379 or Redis is still running.

Comment: how to kill it? @KlausD.

Comment: This was when trying to start for the first time,the server was never run successfully  before @KlausD.

Comment: solved it @KlausD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An instance of redis was already running! Killed it using :

```
$ /etc/init.d/redis-server stop
```